# Java Rotating Icon in JLabel

Tags: java, image, rotation, icons, jlabel

Hi I'm having a problem trying to rotate an image inside a `JLabel`. I got this code from StackOverflow, and I'm trying to change it a little bit so that instead of the image rotating in a Tab, it is rotating within a `JLabel`.

```java
public class ProgressTabbedPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("RotatingIcon"); 
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                JLabel lable = new JLabel();
              

                
                tabbedPane.addTab("Searching", new RotatingIcon(new ImageIcon("disk.png"), tabbedPane, 10), new JLabel( /*new ImageIcon( "resources/images/rotatingIcon.gif" )*/));               
                frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);                
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private static class RotatingIcon implements Icon {

        private final Icon delegateIcon;
        private double angleInDegrees = 90;
        final private Timer rotatingTimer;

        private RotatingIcon(Icon icon, final JComponent component, int vrotating) {
            delegateIcon = icon;
            rotatingTimer = new Timer(vrotating, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                    angleInDegrees = angleInDegrees + 1;
                    if (angleInDegrees == 360) {
                        angleInDegrees = 0;
                    }
                    component.repaint();
                
                }
            });
            rotatingTimer.setRepeats(false);
            rotatingTimer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            rotatingTimer.stop();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int cWidth = delegateIcon.getIconWidth() / 2;
            int cHeight = delegateIcon.getIconHeight() / 2;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, delegateIcon.getIconWidth(), delegateIcon.getIconHeight());
            g2.setClip(r);
            AffineTransform original = g2.getTransform();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.concatenate(original);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angleInDegrees), x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
            g2.setTransform(at);
            delegateIcon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
            g2.setTransform(original);
            rotatingTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return delegateIcon.getIconWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return delegateIcon.getIconHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

This is working, the image is rotating.
However when i change it to this.

```java
public class ProgressTabbedPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("RotatingIcon"); 
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                JLabel lable = new JLabel();
              

                
                
                lable.setIcon(new RotatingIcon(new ImageIcon(disk.png"), tabbedPane, 10));                
                frame.getContentPane().add(lable);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private static class RotatingIcon implements Icon {

        private final Icon delegateIcon;
        private double angleInDegrees = 90;
        final private Timer rotatingTimer;

        private RotatingIcon(Icon icon, final JComponent component, int vrotating) {
            delegateIcon = icon;
            rotatingTimer = new Timer(vrotating, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                    angleInDegrees = angleInDegrees + 1;
                    if (angleInDegrees == 360) {
                        angleInDegrees = 0;
                    }
                    component.repaint();
                
                }
            });
            rotatingTimer.setRepeats(false);
            rotatingTimer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            rotatingTimer.stop();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int cWidth = delegateIcon.getIconWidth() / 2;
            int cHeight = delegateIcon.getIconHeight() / 2;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, delegateIcon.getIconWidth(), delegateIcon.getIconHeight());
            g2.setClip(r);
            AffineTransform original = g2.getTransform();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.concatenate(original);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angleInDegrees), x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
            g2.setTransform(at);
            delegateIcon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
            g2.setTransform(original);
            rotatingTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return delegateIcon.getIconWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return delegateIcon.getIconHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

This stopped working, I'm sorry if it is a stupid question, but I don't seem to find the answer.

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be working for only two turns then it stops working

Comment: I'm not sure you want to repeatedly stop/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A painting method should only be used to paint something. It should not stop/start a Timer. So I would guess that you need get rid of the Timer logic from the painting method and then set the Timer to repeat so that continuous events are generated.

For an alternative approach check out the [Animated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/).

The `Animated Icon` will hold a list of Icons to display sequentially based on a Timer. When the Timer fires the next Icon in the cycle is displaye. You can configure the animation to be continuous or specify the number of cycles to display each Icon.

Note: this solution should be more efficient because it only repaints the Icon, not the entire Component.

If you don't like the idea of creating all the Icons for the animation then you can use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/). With this class you set the degrees of rotation for the Icon. Then the Timer becomes completely separated from the class. Then when the Timer code fires you would increment the degrees of rotation.

Simple example using the `AnimatedIcon`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("1", new JPanel());
        tabbedPane.add("2", new JPanel());
        add(tabbedPane);

        AnimatedIcon icon = new AnimatedIcon(tabbedPane, 250, 3);
        ImageIcon duke = new ImageIcon( "copy16.gif" );
        icon.addIcon( duke );

        for (int angle = 30; angle < 360; angle += 30)
        {
            icon.addIcon( new RotatedIcon(duke, angle) );
        }

        tabbedPane.setIconAt(0, icon);
        icon.start();
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try what you suggested, although the image isn't rotating. Don't know why, i copy the code from the page.

Comment: @Puzzero, see edit. Maybe you forgot to start the animation? Don't forget to post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when saying something doesn't work. We can't guess what your code might be.

Comment: I manage to get my other code working, however i want to use your solution. i dont know where im failing to implement it,

Comment: i get your code running, thank you!, however it seems to run slower, than mine. I get my other code working.

Comment: @Puzzero, `it seems to run slower, than mine.` you can configure the Timer speed to be whatever you want. Your example code is 10, mine is 250.